# Location and responsibilities of Main class in MVC pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am trying to build a simple currency converter using SWING and MVC. My question is: in an MVC pattern **where should be the Main class generally located?** Should it be in a separate package initializing the model, view, controller and setting up the connections etc.? or should the Main class be in the View package? In other words, **whose responsibility is to build the whole system?**

Comment: what is your app made of ? , swing/simple java program/ what ?

Comment: It's a currency converter that uses swing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> where should be the Main class generally located ?

`Main` class should just act as initilizer of the app, you can place it in a package called

`com.yourcompany.currencyconverter.app.main`

> Should it be in a separate package initializing the model, view, controller and setting up the connections etc. ?

Yes, it would be nice to have it separated from the rest.